# To what does energy belong in an energy diagram?

Tags: energy

I was reading [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/100592/binding-energy-in-fission) and I saw an energy diagram:

[image: Energy Diagram]

Does the energy belong to the system or to the outside?

Comment: I mean "the system" (~reactants)

Comment: What "energy" are you referring to here?

Comment: The energy mentioned in the vertical Axis.

Comment: That bar represents the direction of an *increase* in energy, much the same way the axis lines for an $x$-$y$ plot.

Comment: it represents the energy change of the reactants to its final state, no?

Comment: Just to be clear, we're talking about the big thick arrow labeled *Energy*, right?

Comment: @KyleKanos exactly

Comment: Okay. That's just an axis label to show the direction of increasing energy (that is, that $E_0$ is a *gain* in energy and $E_1+E_2$ is a *loss* in energy).

Comment: gain for the system and loss also for the system, right?

Comment: Another question, where goes the energy released in a nuclear reaction, is it kinetic energy or heat ?

Comment: Maybe you should ask this question to the original answer you link, the person who drew the diagram, in a comment there. I see maybe you cannot comment. I will alert John.

Comment: "kinetic energy or heat" Heat is related to the  average kineti energy . if fission products are gammas, the energy can be captured/scattered in material which will then be heated. The same is true for the other fragments, but different materials are efficient for different particles in converting the kinetic energy by scatterings to heat in the convertor material. Eventually for usages steam is produced from reactors which drives conventional engines to produce electricity

Answer (score 1):

The big arrow labelled energy is just an axis. It's supposed to indicate the upwards is positive, i.e. energy is being added to the system, and downwards is negative, i.e. energy is being emitted from the system.

Re the extra question:

> where does the energy released in a nuclear reaction go, is it kinetic energy or heat?

Heat is a collective phenomenon. It doesn't make sense to ask about how much heat a single object has. At the individual particle level all reactions produce either photons or kinetic energy. In the latter case the energy is released as the kinetic energy of the reaction products. There is a discussion of this in my answer to [Can we make usable energy from subnuclear particles?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/91951/can-we-make-usable-energy-from-subnuclear-particles).