# Non-conversion of mass & energy?

Tags: nuclear-physics, mass, photons, mass-energy

This article is certainly an interesting alternative perspective, but is it factual or does it contain fallacies?

http://www.circlon-theory.com/HTML/EmcFallacies.html

Are mass and energy not convertible after all? Do photons really have kinetic mass?

Is it really fair to classify the energy stored in the nuclear strong force as "rotational kinetic energy"?

Comment: Helpful: http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/11460/10826

Comment: Purest nonsense; relativity denialism; utterly unable to deal with the simplest realities of particle experimentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you collide two protons in the LHC you get lots of particles coming out of the collision, and the total mass of these particles is far greater than the mass of the two protons. So the LHC demonstrates the conversion of energy to matter every day.